# Detecting computer models , e.g the vendor

Tags: hardware

How can I detect the model of a computer, like Leveno or Sony?

Is there any program can do this, for both PC & Laptop?

(I just want to load a specific driver when the target model is detected.)

Comment: @walOck, are you writing a shell script? A C program? An udev rule?

Comment: @andcoz , yeah , a shell script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my system, this works:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 1 | grep 'Product Name'
    Product Name: Macmini4,1
```

Comment: Yeah , that's the right command , actually plus `dmidecode -t BIOS | grep Vendor` solved my problem .. thanks !